# Can't find function st_join in R sf package

Tags: r, sf

I am trying to run the st_join example from the sf user manual https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/sf.pdf (p. 43).

```
a = st_sf(a = 1:3, geom = st_sfc(st_point(c(1,1)), st_point(c(2,2)), st_point(c(3,3))))

b = st_sf(a = 11:14, geom = st_sfc(st_point(c(10,10)), st_point(c(2,2)), st_point(c(2,2)), st_point(c(3,3))))

st_join(a, b)
```

I get the error message that R can't find the function sf_join.
I am running R 3.3.2 on x86_64-w64-mingw32
I installed sf0.3.1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just quickly, have loaded the library before running the example code above, eg `library("sf")`.  That should bring up a message about linking to GEOS, GDAL and proj.4

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade `sf`. `st_join` is very recent and I've got it with the latest CRAN version which is 0.3.4.

https://github.com/edzer/sfr/commit/3f7c25dbae8972a3ce031e4823dcf943ca69b98e